# How to disable mac toolbar auto switch between screens

Tags: macos, mac, toolbar

I have a second monitor. Even if I never use toolbar in the second screen, mac automatically shows toolbar on the second screen due to unintentional mouse gesture. I end up with the fixing the situation constantly.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's called the **Dock**, btw.

If you use the setting 'Displays have separate Spaces'* then the Dock [& menu bar] will move to whichever display you have currently active. It has to, to know which Space you're talking to at any given time.

If you disable this setting, the displays/Spaces will move in pairs & the Dock & menu bar will stay where you put them, on the primary display.

You can aggressively kill the Dock process, which will move it back to the primary, if it really bothers you, with `sudo killall Dock`

*In System Preferences > Mission Control before Ventura
In System Settings > Desktop & Dock in Ventura.

Comment: I'm curious what is currently active, because as I'm typing on this screen, the dock is not moving to this screen.  So how does mac determine the active screen?

Comment: Hit the bottom of the screen with the cursor, as far as I know. I don't use separate spaces, so I can't test.